# 2 different controllers in abstract view

Tags: angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

here is the thing

```
<ion-tabs ng-controller="LoginCtrl">

  <!-- News Tab -->
  <ion-tab href="#/tabs/news">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-news"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab href="#/tabs/promotions">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-promotions"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab href="#/tabs/signup">
    <ion-nav-view name="signup"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

this is a mobile app, and this is the abstract view, I have there the LoginCtrl attached because I need it everywhere, but also, I need another controller to be present everywhere. I need it present everywhere because this is an streaming music app, so the music must be in every view with out stopping. So, what options do I have ? the LoginCtrl is already defined there, I need to set up another controller named `AudioCtrl`.

Comment: There are lots of UI components you can use in ionic framework . What is stopping you from using any of them for your audio controller?

Comment: actually I fix it already, I declare LoginCtrl as the parent Controller in the body tag, and put AudioCtrl in the abstract view, I need both to be in every view.

Comment: just sounds like you didn't try anything before asking

Comment: do not put words in my mouth that I have never said. Someone just answer my question. Thanks

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer, why do you even need this to be a controller and not a service? Also, how is the fact that it is an abstract view related to having multiple controllers; I fail to see the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any number of controllers to your html, Just add some more divs to to this like this:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
<ion-tabs ng-controller="AudioCtrl">

  <!-- News Tab -->
  <ion-tab href="#/tabs/news">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-news"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-tab>

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
 <ion-tab href="#/tabs/promotions">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-promotions"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-tab>

 <!-- Account Tab -->
 <ion-tab href="#/tabs/signup">
   <ion-nav-view name="signup"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, someone willing to help, a miracle. Have a nice one